# Angular4/TypeScript Class Usability

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is that possible to access two different Typescript classes like controller to store a value...here is my use case....
i'm getting values from the front end lets say i have `ID="100",Name="Angular4"`. Now how can i pass those values to these class using the methods get `getFieldValue(fieldName: string)` and `setFieldValue(fieldValue: string, value: string)`. Also i have tried to instantiate the classes to get or set the value but i got failed,can anybody please tell how can i acheive the desired output completely using typescript?

my classes are:

**main class**:

```
import {Record} from './record';
import {Field} from './field';
export class BusinessObject {

    public boName: string = null;
    public focusedRecordsList = new Set();
    // public activeRecord: Record = new Record();
    public fetchSize: number = 100;
    // public activeParentRecord: Record = new Record();
    public hasMoreRows: boolean;
    public isPageQuery: boolean;
    public startIndex: number;



    public createNewRecord(boName: string, parentId: string, fromRecord: string) {
        return JSON.stringify({'boName': boName, 'parentId': parentId, 'fromRecord': fromRecord});
    }

getFieldValue(fieldName: string): any {

}

    setFieldValue(fieldValue: string, value: string): void {

    }
```

}

and another **class, that contains my field types**:

```
import {BusinessObject} from './business-object';
export class Field extends BusinessObject{

     // Specifies different information on the field
     public name: string    = null;
     public id: string      = null;
     public type: string    = null;
     public boId: string    = null;
     public colName: string = null;



     constructor(name: string) {

     }


}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: This is way too much irrelevant code. Please remove the irrelevant stuff so its easier to understand.

Comment: now i removed irrelevant stuff

Comment: Use a service, store there the data(a obj) and the get it when you want

Comment: Thanks for the idea francesco